# components is not working in angular js 2

Tags: angular

Default component is :

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {MyComponentComponent} from './mycomponentcomponent';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>Angular 2  Demo</h1>
        <p>Hello World Testing</p>
        <test-app></test-app>

    `,
    directories:[MyComponentComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

And Second Component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'test-app',
    template: '
        <h1>TEST APP</h1>
        <p>TEST APP -> Hello World Testing 12</p>
    ',
})
export class MyComponentComponent {

}
```

But it is showing a javascript error.  May i know please where am i doing mistake?

Comment: Please add the exact error message to your question.

Comment: `directories` should be `directives`, I guess you are using older version of angular2, please upgrade it to Angular 2 final

Comment: which version are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

**For older version of Angular2**,

change

```
directories:[MyComponentComponent]
```

to

```
directives:[MyComponentComponent]
```

---

**For newer version of Angular2**,

please remove `directories:[MyComponentComponent]` from **@Component({})** of **AppComponent**

and add it to **@NgModule({})** as shown here,

```
@NgModule({
   ...
   declarations :[AppComponent, MyComponentComponent]
})
```